# Masonry multiple image width

Tags: jquery, css, masonry

I successfully implemented Masonry script but I cannot fit the layout base on mockup. My layout has different width for the images. I tried many ways and still trying. I even tried custom width for different size image, example

```
.hotspot { width:47.38%}
.secpos { width:27.69%}
.thepos { width:24.7%}
```

Do you guys have any idea how I can fix this problem?

my exmple `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGybGb` there all width is `width: 33.333%;`

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  // init Masonry
  var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
   columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
  });
  // layout Isotope after each image loads
  $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $grid.masonry();
  });  

});
```

check my mockup `https://dribbble.com/shots/2307670-Magazine-Website-Layout/attachments/437382`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup is fine, but you need to define different grid sizes, in the design, I see at least 3 different widths: 33.3333%, 30%, and 40% (the big one). Another detail is that `.grid-sizer` width should be the min width you are going to use.

Hacking your pen a little bit, this is the idea:
http://codepen.io/tomsarduy/pen/KdQWXz

Note: Also, play with the heights and try `background-image` on `.grid-item`

Comment: thanks you so much. it is work almost but there have issue which i got early also check my `http://codepen.io/pagol/pen/PPQWdB` if you see 1st column fit nicely . i play with height already there. but underneath if u see _Elegant & Alluring Nyonya Dress_ go to far from _How to Break_ , may be i understand why, because i think  columnWidth took 50% width default or else. do you that solution please

Comment: i notice in 2nd row 1st image position taking     left: 50%; that's why got big space. no idea where to fix

Comment: @pagol: Yes, it's a bit rare, seems like it's not working like it suppose to, so I set `columnWidth: 1`, since it's the maximum common denominator, this is the result: http://codepen.io/tomsarduy/pen/KdQWXz

Comment: thank you so much it work. :) thanks a ton. now need to play with css more. it working fine if container size 1200px max but when i make 1366 it again broken and i played already with css it can be fixable i understand but not so easy. isn't have any way to fit always nice 1366px or more less or width no mater.

or have any other masonry plugins which can handle image size nicely fit